# Generics in ASP.NET MVC Controller Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, controller

In ASP.NET MVC **3**, how can I do something like that?

```
public JsonResult Create<T>(T field) where T : Field
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a gerneric Controller.

```
public abstract class BaseFieldController<T> : Controller where T : Field
{
    public virtual JsonResult Create(T field)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then extend from it

```
public class FieldController : BaseFieldController<Field>
{

}
```

Comment: Umm, and how would its Url look like?

Comment: I can't extend it. Is there anyway to somehow do this in routing? Such as `/BaseFieldController/GenericName/Create`?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't extend your controller from another controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SpecificField : Field
{
    ...
}

public class SpecificController : BaseController<SpecificField>
{
    ....
}

public class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : Field
{
    public JsonResult Create( T field )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```